# Persian/Arabic text problem in SVG files (in Photoshop V21)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg

I have an SVG file which contains some Persian text, despite I have set the 'Language Options' to 'Middle Eastern Features' and I can type a text correctly in new documents, when I open the SVG file, there will be a problem like this picture:

[image]

Edit:

1. The main problem is that all the characters of words separated. for example, we have this word in Persian: `شهریور` but in the SVG file it's converted to `ش ه ر ی و ر` (without any space).
2. Web browsers show the SVG correctly.
3. I've no idea about its outline styles because it's an export file from a software.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's hard for anyone who can't read Persian\Arabic script to tell what is wrong here.  [Please edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/140347/edit) and describe what the problem actually is.  Also is this editable text, or has it been converted to outlines?  Does the SVG work in a browser?  Have you tried opening it in a vector image editor instead? If this works you could then convert the text to outlines to avoid any problems when importing into Photoshop.

Comment: Since many here may not speak the language.... I have no idea what "the problem like this" even is....

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi and thanks, I've updated the question. Please check it out.

Comment: @Scott I've updated the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: You can tell if it's outlines if the text is made using paths and fills, and it's not actual editable text.  Ok, so if the text is still editable text, then try this. Open the SVG in Illustrator, or Inkscape. Convert the text to outlines.  Then save it as SVG. Now import this new SVG into Photoshop.

Comment: @BillyKerr I've done this, but nothing has changed. I think the SVG file doesn't have any problem because it's opened by browsers correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You can open your file with Adobe illustrator and convert Persian/Arabic text to “Shape”. Then export it as svg.

How to convert Text to Shape:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIE7-Hge2RE

[image]

After converting text to shape:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand or read Persian, but looking at the differences between your two examples, it looks like you're having a problem with ligatures.

I'm not sure how that would affect an SVG import however.

Take a look at this palette in Illustrator and try playing with turning things on and off?
[image: OpenType Palette]

Another thing to try would be to open a new document, confirm that you can type in it correctly, then try to place the SVG in the new document.